# UIView Subclass Init

Tags: ios, objective-c

I subclassed the UIView and have some properties in it like the background colour. I initialised the colour in the provided `initWithFrame:frame` function but it doesn't work. I tried `init` as well but it doesn't work either. So where should I put the initialisation?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using storybard or nib to load the view. In this case you should override the initWithCoder.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if ( self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]){
        NSLog(@"cmd %@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

hope this help.

Comment: @Vincent Would in this case awakeFromNib also work? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig Yes it will.

Comment: YES! the initWithCoder will be invoke first then the awakeFromNib.